# Symfony - Unknown MySQL server host when using command line

Tags: php, symfony, docker, doctrine-orm

So for some reason when I run for example `cache:clear` I get the following error:

[image: mysql error]

But when I view the application through the browser it seem to connect fine to the database because when I edit the parameters.yml with incorrect data it throws an error in the browser saying it cannot connect.

I'm using docker and i have the following settings:

```
php:
  image: zimmobe/php:5.6-apache-oraclelinux
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/project/
  environment:
    - SYMFONY_ENV=dev
    - SYMFONY_DEBUG=1
    - BASE_DIR=/var/www/project
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 3005:80

mysql:
   image: mysql:5.6
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_DATABASE: minecraftweb
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
```

and my parameters.yml looks like this:

```
parameters:
    database_host: mysql
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: minecraftweb
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

So any reason why the command line throws an error but not the application in the browser?

Comment: are you executing the command inside the php container?

Comment: oh well... that seems to work much better :D. i'm new to docker. thx!

Comment: I was running the clear command in the folder of the project but not in a specific container. just in the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should launch the command inside the container, an example ( of a probably script):

```
docker-compose \
    -f docker-compose.yml \
    run --rm --entrypoint bash php -c \
    "id -u dockeruser &> /dev/null || useradd -r -g users -u $USER_ID --base-dir /tmp dockeruser && su dockeruser -c 'bin/console cache:clear'"
```

Hope this help